# Check if an user is G Suite user or not

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, integration, google-workspace

So in our signup page we have following requirements :

> 1. Identify if the user (doing signup) is a G Suite user or not.
> 2. If yes then details of admin of that organization.

Is it possible to get these two details using apis of G Suite.
I have checked the documentation, but not sure if any api will fulfill my requirement.

Kindly advice.